# Getting a List<Items> out of List<List<Items>>

Tags: c#

I have a object called Items. I use that object like so.

```
List<List<Items>> myItems = new List<List<Items>>();
```

I want to know how to get a specific `List<Items>` out of the `List<List<Items>>` object. Currently I am using foreach loops with some rules to find a specific `List<Items>`

This is currently what I am doing

```
foreach (List<Items> db2Items in db2Data)
{
     foreach (List<Items> apiItems in apiData)
     {
          if (db2Items[0].Value == apiItems[0].Value && db2Items[27].Value == apiItems[27].Value)
          {
               /// Some other logic here
          }
     }
}
```

I was wanting to use LINQ to get the matching `List<items>` out of apiData and if I have a result then do the logic I wanted to do.

Comment: Could you share what you have done so far?

Comment: How are you identifying the specific `List<Items>` instance that you want - e.g., the "rules" that you mention?

Comment: Added some code of what I am currently doing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have figured it out.

Using LINQ:

```
foreach (List<Items> db2Items in db2Data)
{
     IEnumerable<List<Items>> theItem = from item in apiData
                                        where item[0].Value == db2Items[0].Value && item[27]>Value == db2Items[27].Value
                                        select item;
     if (theItem.ToList().Count > 0)
     {
          // Do something
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're trying to accomplish, but if you want to get a list in a list based on a certain condition you can do it like this:

var item = db2Data.Where(x => x.Where(y => y.[value] == [YourCondition]).Any()).FirstOrDefault();

the "x.Where(y => y == [YourCondition]).Any()" will return true if the condition is met, and firstordefault will then return the list that meets the condition.